# Simple chat app (Should I use sockets? And would Apple app store approve that?)

Tags: sockets, app-store

I have an idea of an application that involves a "chat feature", basically an ability for people to chat with each other. Since sending messages through a server would be slow (plus it would be pretty bad having to check the server every second if you have new messages) I want to use sockets to have peer to peer chat ability instead of going through a server.

My 2 questions:

1) Is socket programming the most optimal way to develop a chat program? I know there is push notification service, but I don't think it can be used for a chat program too well. Going through a server seems kind of bad if you imagine 5,000 people chatting and having to poll the server every second.

2) Will Apple have issues approving an app that has peer to peer chat program that uses sockets?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Sockets are indeed appropriate.  But you are better off with a client/server approach rather than a P2P approach.

Having worked on a very well known instant messaging service for many years, I can tell you absolutely that going through a server is not slow - as long as your server is not slow.

Client/server has lots of advantages. Namely, it's not as difficult as any sort of P2P connectivity where such issues as NATs and Firewalls make direct socket connections difficult and unreliable.  Besides, you would need a messaging service anyway for clients to exchange IP addresses.

Your stated assumption that a client or server would have to "poll" is not how scalable systems work. You should use a persistent TCP socket and look at scaling a socket service up though any of the available async methods that exist today.  select(), poll(), epoll on Linux, and IO Completion Ports on Windows are all techniques for having thousands of sockets simultaneously connected without periodic polling.

My suggestion - just deploy an XMPP/Jabber server.  Most implementations scale up nicely to the thousands of clients.  Then your chat program is just an XMPP client socket. Some of the Jabber servers even support HTTP connectivity for situations where a user's only access is via an http or http proxy server.  I played around with [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp) a while back and was reasonably impresseed.

I'm fairly certain that iOS has sockets, and that it's allowed by Apple. I only know via second hand from folks that have worked on iOS products. You probably shouldn't use the push notification service for anything more than notifications to wake up your app that there is something it needs to do.

Hope this helps.